# Smarty Remove Everything Between one specific Word and the next Comma

Tags: regex, string, smarty

I would like to **replace with smarty a string** in a variable (for some reasons, I can only do this with Smarty, and not with php)

I know that the Smarty line to write would have the following shape :
{$MyVar|escape:"htmlall"|regex_replace:xxxxxx}

But, I do not know what to put after replace.

In the variable value a string has the here after shape :

- Toto abcd1234,
- Toto is always the same word
- abcd1234 could be any alphanumeric character or space
- The comma (,) is the end of the string to delete

The string could be at the beginning, middle or end of the variable value.

I would like to delete :

- the string between Toto and the next comma
- or (better) delete both    Toto, the string and the comma

Thank you in advance for any help.

Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the whole substring from `Toto` till and including the comma, you can use

```
|regex_replace:'/\bToto[^,]*,/':""
```

Or if you use a standalone variable:

```
{'/\bToto[^,]*,/'|preg_replace:'':$MyVar}
```

The [regex demo is here](https://regex101.com/r/bI8uL5/1)

Regex breakdown:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `Toto` - word "Toto"
- `[^,]*` - 0 or more symbols other than `,`
- `,` - a literal comma

Comment: Hi,

Thank you very much for your reply.

The code works like a charm, when it is alone.

But, I have already this smarty code related to the variable modification :
{$MyVar|escape:"htmlall"|replace:".":" "|strstr:':':false|replace:'Word1':'Word2'}

I tried simply to add your code at the end of mine :
{$MyVar|escape:"htmlall"|replace:".":" "|strstr:':':false|replace:'Word1':'Word2'|preg_replace:'':'/\bTaille[^,]*,/'}

But it gives an error : Warning: preg_replace(): No ending delimiter ':'

Thank you again in advance for your help.

Patrick

Comment: Try adding to your piped code: `|replace:'\bTaille[^,]*,':''`. Or `|regex_replace:'/\bTaille[^,]*,/':""`.

Comment: |regex_replace:'/\bTaille[^,]*,/':"" works perfectly. Thnak you very much indeed to stribizhev. Patrick